# Calculus 2 Limits and L'Hospitals

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} 6\sqrt{x^2+10x}-6x$$

I multiplied this problem by its conjugate and that seems to work except I get stuck on one portion and keep getting $-\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ for one specific part of the problem. Also the answer I know is $\frac{360}{12}$

Comment: I edited your question to make it a little more clear.  Please check out [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for references for formatting your mathematics.

Comment: no fractions missing, this is exactly it :)

Answer (score 4):

So, we have - as you write - by multiplying with the conjugate
$$ 6\sqrt{x^2 + 10x} - 6x = \frac{36(x^2 + 10x) - 36x^2}{6\sqrt{x^2 + 10x} + 6x} $$
Now divide numerator and denoninator by $x$, giving
$$ 6 \sqrt{x^2 +10x} - 6x = \frac{360}{6\sqrt{1 + \frac{10}x} + 6} $$
for $x \to \infty$ the right hand side converges to $30$.

Comment: Got it!! Thanks Just needed to remember to divide by sqrt(x^2)